# How can I capture terminal output from a bash script and display it in my Qt UI?

Tags: c++, bash, qt, user-interface, qprocess

I've written a simple GUI that guides the user through a checkout/checkin procedure, and then runs a bash script when the user clicks a GUI button.

I'd like to create a field within the GUI and display the output of the script. Right now I'm using `system()` (stdio) to run the script, but piping the script's output to a text field in my gui seems messy.

Would using `QProcess` be a better approach?
If so, how would I get started?

Also, what Qt Widget/container would you recommend?

Comment: `QProcess` would make this easy.

Answer (score 8):

> Would using QProcess be a better approach? If so, how would I get started?

By looking at the [QProcess documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html), you can do something similar to this:

```
QString program = "/usr/bin/ls";
QStringList arguments{"-lahR"};
QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
myProcess->start(program, arguments);
connect(myProcess, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [myProcess] {
  qDebug() << "Got output from process:" << myProcess->readAllStandardOutput();
  // Or copy the data to QPlainTextEdit::appendPlainText()
});
```

You probably also want to capture standard error output. You can either do a second `connect()` or use [`QProcess::setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#ProcessChannelMode-enum).

Executing shell scripts with `QProcess` should work fine, as long as they are marked with `#! interpreter [optional-arg]` at the beginning. This is because `QProcess` internally uses `fork` + `execvp`, and the [documentation for that](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) clearly states shell scripts are allowed.

Don't forget to delete your `QProcess` when the command has finished.

> Also, what Qt Widget/container would you reccomend?

Sounds like a job for [QPlainTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html). Alternatively, you can use the slower [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html), which brings additional features.

Comment: You mention that QProcess can not execute shell scripts directly -- I just tested this on Qt 5.5 and it worked without issue. Do your scripts have the `#!/bin/[ba]sh` shebang line? Are they marked executable?

Comment: Thannks for the reccomendation, I'm tinkering with this QProccess method now

Comment: @PaulB Oh indeed, you are right, shell scripts are allowed, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the answer to reflect that.